# Monkey patched django auth's login, now its tests fail

Tags: django, monkeypatching, django-authentication

My app seeks to wrap the django.contrib.auth.views login and logout views with some basic auditing/logging capabilities.  I'm following the prescription as described in the [django-axes](http://code.google.com/p/django-axes/) project, and in running on a server and some other tests, it works as expected, transparently without issue.

The code goes like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from myapp.watchers import watch_login

class WatcherMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self):
        auth_views.login = watch_login(auth_views.login)
```

And

```
def watch_login(func):
    def decorated_login(request, *args, **kwargs):
        #do some stuff
        response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        #more stuff
        return response
    return decorated_login
```

Urls:

```
#Edit: Added project's urls - just using vanilla django's auth login
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',{"template_name":settings.LOGIN_TEMPLATE }),
```

However, in our build workflow, we run into some issues in the django.contrib.auth.tests.views.

Specifically, these are the tests that fail in django.contrib.auth:

```
ERROR: test_current_site_in_context_after_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tests\views.py", line 192, in test_current_site_in_context_after_login
    response = self.client.get(reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login'))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 351, in reverse
    *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 297, in reverse
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'myapp.watchers.decorated_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

======================================================================
ERROR: test_security_check (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\tests\views.py", line 204, in test_security_check
    login_url = reverse('django.contrib.auth.views.login')
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 351, in reverse
    *args, **kwargs)))
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 297, in reverse
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'myapp.watchers.decorated_login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

Only these two tests fail with the inclusion of the wrapped login monkey patch.
It seems like the reverse() call in the django auth test behaves differently than how an unpatched function does its thing.

The reason why we're going this route for wrapping logging vs. using django 1.3's new authentication signals is because the logging method provided there only tells you if a wrong attempts happens - it doesn't give you access to the request object to log additional information around that improper request.  Patching the authentication form in that case would not have been helpful, hence our need to wrap the login function.

Am I doing something wrong with my wrap of the login function?  Or is this as to be expected with tests failing due to other side effects, despite no change in overall functionality?

edit: I'm running python 2.6.4, django 1.2.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couldn't you simply wrap it in another view?

**`urls`:**

```
url(
    r'^accounts/login/$',
    'accounts.views.login',
    {"template_name":settings.LOGIN_TEMPLATE }
),
```

**`accounts.views`:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views   

def login(request, *args, **kwars):
    # do some stuff    
    response = auth_views.login(request, *args, **kwars)
    # more stuff
    return response
```

Like this, `django.contrib.auth.tests` will be testing the view which they were written for and you can write your own tests for the "more stuff" you need.

Comment: I suppose that that may be the final solution to consider - it was something I wanted to avoid.  The wrapped login() method you mention is what I wanted to do transparently via monkey patch.  I wanted this solution to be an easy way to plug in an auditing method without too code/config alteration (effectively say settings.AUDIT_LOGIN=True to magically do the trick), but it looks like for tests to pass I may need to force users of our code to just explicitly wrap/override.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is the same underlying issue [that affects django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/issue/81/tests-fail-if-templates-use-url-tag) in that the test runner only imports the URLs of the app being tested at the time -- ie, `contrib.auth` and not `myapp` There are [various](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11077) [tickets](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10747) about things [similar to this issue](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10976) but a quick scan of them implies the solution is to decouple things, which isn't going to be viable for your solution I'm guessing.

Another way around it would be to use Fabric file or Makefile to trigger a subset of tests, avoiding the two that fail because of your monkeypatch, and then add two alternate ape-friendly tests to replace them.

Comment: The weird thing is that the tests failing are django's own auth tests.  myapp's urls aren't even in the picture here.  The app's init monkeypatches the django auth init, and explicitly calling the auth's viewname (that's what the django auth test is doing) is where the failure is.  Is the monkeypatched view somehow being reverse called again when trying to resolve the wrapped function?